# Adding additonal Selected value in Select2 on button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, jquery-select2

The scenario is, I need to append a value (a selected Value) to select2 by just clicking a button. What happen is if I click my button, the other values I selected are gone/cleared.

Only 1 value is selected which is the value in my button function.  I could select multiple values when typing directly to my select2 textbox, but then if i clicked the button, its value doesn't add to select2.

How do i append a value or push an additional value to data already selected in select2 on my click Button? a new value should be added to select2 selected values everytime I click the button.

I hope my code below, and my description to what im looking for kinda help you guys.  Thank you.

I'm using Northwind DataBase, for testing it.  (Robert King is under Employee Table)

```
<input type="button" onclick="Passvalue();"/>
<input type="text" id="eq" name="eq" style="width: 200px;" />

<script>
    $(function () {       
        $("#eq").select2({
            minimumInputLength: 3,
            multiple: true,
            ajax: {
                url: '/Employee/GetAllEmployees/',
                dataType: 'json',
                type: "GET",
                data: function (searhTerm) {               
                    return { query: searhTerm };
                },
                results: 
                    function (data) {                
                        return { results: data};
                    },                             
            },
            initSelection: function (element, callback) {
                var id=$(element).val();  //element value will be 'Robert';
                if (id!=="") {
                    $.ajax('/Employee/GetAllEmployees/', {
                        data: {
                            query: id
                        },
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "GET",
                    }).done(function(data) { callback(data); });
                }               
                },
            createSearchChoice: function (term) {          
                return {id: term, text: term + ' (new)', title: term };    
            },

            formatResult: FormatContact,
            formatSelection: FormatContactSelection,
            escapeMarkup: function(m) {
                return m;
            }
        });
    });

    function FormatContact(contact) {

        return contact.text + "&nbsp;(" + contact.title + ")";
    }

    function FormatContactSelection(contact) {
        return " &nbsp; &nbsp;"+ contact.text;
    }

    function Passvalue() { 
        var test2 = "Robert"; //just an example, value 'Robert' to be passed on select2 for query     
        $('#eq').select2("val", [test2]);    
    }
</script>
```

My Action Controller:

```
public ActionResult GetAllEmployees(string query)
            {
                var db = new Employee().GetAllEmployees(query).
                    ToList();        
                return Json(db, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
```

BL:

```
public IQueryable<Object> GetAllEmployees(string search)
        {
            var ctx = new NorthwindEntities();
            var dbQuery =
            (from i in ctx.Employees
             where i.FirstName.Contains(search) || i.LastName.Contains(search)
             select new
                    {
                        id = i.EmployeeID,
                        text = i.FirstName + " " + i.LastName,
                        title = i.Title
                    });
           return dbQuery;
        }
```

Comment: I am not familiar with select2 much.But You can Refer this
http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/select2-latest.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using "val" use "data". Something like this

```
this.$("#yourSelector").select2("data", [{ id: 1, text: "Some Text" },{ id: 2, text: "Some Other Text" }]);
```

So something like this would work for you...

```
var existingData = this.$("#yourSelector").select2("data");
existingData.push({ id: 11, text: "Some Text" });
this.$("#yourSelector").select2("data", existingData);
```

P.S : I have not tested the above code.

Comment: ive use this code below: from your answer                    data.push({ id: id, text: text });
$('#myselector').select2("data", data, true);  // to refresh select2 data value